# scala override protected member function

Tags: scala

I wanted to instantiate a trait and override a protected function *g*, making it accessible (function *f* is for testing).

```
trait A {
    protected def g( i: Int ) = println( i )
    def f( i: Int ) = println( i )
}
```

I created an object a1

```
val a1= new A {
    override def f( i: Int ) = super.f(i)
    override def g( i: Int ) = super.g(i)
    def h( i: Int ) = super.g(i)
}
```

and tried to call the methods

```
a1.f(1)
a1.g(3)    // this call fails
a1.h(5)
```

For *a1.g(3)* I get this error:

```
<console>:10: error: method g in trait A cannot be accessed in A{def h(i: Int): Unit}
   Access to protected method g not permitted because
   enclosing object $iw is not a subclass of 
   trait A where target is defined
                      a1.g(3)    // this call fails
```

But when I define a trait *A2* extending *A* and overriding the methods *f* and *g*, create an instance of it and call the methods, all works fine

```
trait A2 extends A {
    override def f( i: Int ) = super.f(i)
    override def g( i: Int ) = super.g(i)
    def h( i: Int ) = super.g(i)
}
val a2= new A2 {}

a2.f(2)
a2.g(4)
a2.h(6)
```

Why is there a difference between

```
val a1= new A {
    override def g( i: Int ) = super.g(i)
}
```

and

```
trait A2 extends A {
    override def g( i: Int ) = super.g(i)
}
val a2= new A2 {}
```

?

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer:  It's a bug.  https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1352

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java protected member is accessible to both subclasses and the package in which the member is defined, in Scala, on the other hand, member is visible only to subclasses.

In your case, the code is probably called from outside of a class implementing A (e.g. from worksheet)

If you want to simulate Java behavior, then you can use notation

```
protected[package_name] def g(i: Int) = println(i)
```

then, the method `g()` will be visible inside the package `package_name`

Comment: My intent was to make a protected method accessible by overriding it  - whether this makes sense or not - I have to think aubout it

Answer (score 4):

I'll just go ahead and make my comment an answer.  [It's a bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1352).  It really should work the way you expect, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to play games with `override` just for testing. You can do something like this:

```
package com.foo.bar

trait MyTrait{
  def stuff(i: Int) = hidden(i) + 1

  protected[bar] hidden(i: Int): Int
}
```

and then in the test file

```
package com.foo.bar

class Testing extends Specification{
  "hidden" must{
    //some tests in here
   }
```

which is another way of saying, "`hidden` is visible at the package level and thus anything within that package can see/test it."

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will try it. I'm new to scala and when I encounter a problem, I write some simple lines of code. Originally I wanted to override _publish_ from _scala.collection.mutable.Publisher_